# Get values from a QDialog

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a QDialog that has two lineEdits and a button. When the button is pressed, I want the QDialog to be closed, and I want the values in the lineEdits to be available to me. Right  now, I have the follwoing:

```
void createDialog()
{
    QDialog dialog;
    QLineEdit *lineEdit1 = new QLineEdit(&dialog);
    QLineEdit *lineEdit2 = new QLineEdit(&dialog);
    QPushButton *ok = new QPushButton("OK", &dialog);
    QVBoxLayout *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    vLayout->addWidget(lineEdit1);
    vLayout->addWidget(lineEdit2);
    vLayout->addWidget(ok);
    dialog.setLayout(vLayout);
    connect(ok, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(processValues()));
    dialog.exec();
}
```

I would like to know how to close the QDialog and access the values of the lineEdits in the processValues() function.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should subclass from QDialog and put all the widgets there. QLineEdits will be members of Dialog and it will have member functions which will return the values of those.

You can see an example here http://thisthread.blogspot.com/2010/06/qdialog-subclass.html.
And here http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405224

[How to pass data from a QDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585774/how-to-pass-data-from-a-qdialog)